# initialise object with equal operator

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer

In the class defined as below named foo

```
class foo{
private:
    string str;
public:
    foo operator = (string s){
         str = s;
    }
};

int main(){
    foo a = "this initialization throwing an error";
    foo b;
    b = "but assignment after declaration is working fine";
}
```

`error: conversion from 'const char [38]' to non-scalar type 'foo' requested`

The above error is caused only when I am assigning value to the object instance with declaration but if I am assigning separately from declaration then the overloaded equal `=` operator is working fine.

I want in any method to assign an string to the object **with equal operator**
and **as a declaration** like `foo a = "abcd";`

Comment: You need a *conversion constructor*, i.e., `foo(const std::string& s) : str(s) {}`

Comment: The code that's failing is not "assigning value to the object..." it is attempting to **initialize** the object, and that requires a constructor.

Comment: You need to build a constructor from a const char*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have

```
type name = something;
```

You are not doing assignment but instead you have *copy-initialization* (do not that there can be a move even though it is called copy).  This means that you need a constructor in your class whose parameter matches that of the thing on the right hand side of the `=`.

In this case you do not have a constructor that takes a `std::string`, `const char*` or `const char[]` so the compiler is unable to construct an instance there.

The reason the second case works is that

```
b = "but assignment after declaration is working fine";
```

Is not trying to construct anything and therefore it calls the assignment operator which does work because

```
"but assignment after declaration is working fine"
```

can be converted to a `std::string`.

If you want your class to be constructable from a string literal or cstring then you can add a constructor to it in the form of

```
foo(const char* str) : str(str) {}
```

Comment: any way to make sure that the data will be taken as `std::string` or `const char*` or `const char[]`   
because in my case i was thinking that it was accepting the data as a `std::string` but only now i found out that it is taking as `const char*`

Comment: @Encryptor Just added to the answer a constructor that should do what you need.

Comment: "or needs to be convertable to one of those types" that is incorrect statement

Comment: @Slava Yep.  I thought that sounded wrong when I typed it.  Thanks for calling me out on it.

Comment: @NathanOliver now your last statement is confusing :)

Answer (score 2):

What you have in the first case is called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and as stated in documentation:

> The equals sign, =, in copy-initialization of a named variable is not
>   related to the assignment operator. Assignment operator overloads have
>   no effect on copy-initialization.

Hense the error. So possible solutions:

First you can create a constructor, that accepts `std::string`:

```
foo( const std::string &s );
```

that will allow you to create `foo` by this:

```
foo f( "abc" );
```

or even this:

```
foo f = foo( "abc" );
```

but your statement will still fail, because of:

> in addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must
>   produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g.
>   direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the
>   initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

so to make your statement work as it is you need to add this ctor:

```
 foo( const char *str );
```

Note: when you add proper ctor you do not need to define assignment operator -  conversion constructor will be used. And your overloaded assignment operator should return reference to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
foo a = "initialization string";
```

attempts to create an object of type foo however there is no constructor defined that accepts a parameter of type string.

You could define one like this:

```
foo(const std::string& s) : str(s) {}
foo(const char* s) : str(s) {}
```

Comment: But then the OP's code would have to create an anonymous temporary std::string. Perhaps a compiler would optimise that out though?

Comment: You could also create a move constructor that accepts an `std::string`. This would solve the problem if you called it with a string literal.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong, this ctor will not fix OP's issue

Comment: @Slava You are right that would not work. I updated the post with a constructor that takes a `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object, the code **initializes** it with a constructor, even when the creation uses an `=` sign:

```
struct S {
    S(int);
};

S s = 3; // initialization, not assignment
```

Formally, that initialization uses `S(int)` to create a temporary object of type `S`, and then uses the copy constructor to construct the object `s` from the temporary object.

That's vastly different from assignment, which deals with an already existing object:

```
S s1;
s1 = 3; // assignment
```

Here, the assignment would use the assignment operator if `S` defined one. That's why the `b =` line in the original code works.

Comment: "Formally, that initialization uses S(int) to create a temporary object of type S" is there any ground for this statement?

Comment: @Slava -yes, it's a requirement in the standard. It's been that way since way before C++ 98.

Comment: But effect is completely different, if I explicitly create temporary then it will allow conversion, which is not allowed otherwise. See my answer.

Comment: @Slava - sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. The effect of `S s = 3;` is, formally, exactly what I described. What I left out, for simplicity, is that the compiler is allowed to elide that copy and construct `s` directly, which is why I used the word "formally".

Comment: I mean that `S s = 3;` and `S s = S(3);` are different statements with different semantics.

Comment: Well, sort of; the second explicitly creates a temporary, and copies it into `s`. But that isn't the example I gave, which implicitly creates a temporary.

Comment: But you said that formally it does that, so it can be understood that semantics is the same, which is not true.

Comment: @Slava -- what, specifically, do you think is incorrect about my statement? "Different semantics" is just handwaving until you explain **exactly** what you think is different from what. The two statements in your previous comment do the same thing, modulo a copy constructor or two.

Comment: if OP would define ctor `foo( const std::string & )` then `foo f = foo( "str" );` would compile but `foo f = "str";`  would not. So it is not the same.

Comment: @Slava - different isn't the same. Your latest requires two user-defined conversions (`char*` to `string`, `string` to `foo`), and that's why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

For starters though the compiler does not issue a diagnostic message nevertheless the assignment operator in the class definition

```
class foo{
private:
    string str;
public:
    foo operator = (string s){
         str = s;
    }
};
```

is invalid because it returns nothing while it has return type `foo`.

You should it write like

```
    foo & operator = ( const std::string &s){
         str = s;
         return *this;
    }
```

As you declared neither the default constructor nor the copy constructor then the compiler implicitly declared them instead of you.

So in fact your class has only two constructor. The default constructor that has the following declaration

```
foo();
```

and the copy constructor that has the following declaration

```
for( const foo & );
```

In this statement

```
foo a = "this initialization throwing an error";
```

the compiler assumes that in the right side there is an object of type `foo` and you are going to use it to create the object `a`. That is in this declaration the compiler tries to apply the implicitly created copy constructor. To so so it need to convert the string literal to an object of type `foo`. However the class does not have a conversion constructor that is a constructor with a parameter that can accept the string literal. As result the compiler issues the error

> error: conversion from 'const char [38]' to non-scalar type 'foo'
>   requested

`const char[33]` is the type of the string literal in the right side of the declaration.

In this code snippet

```
foo b;
b = "but assignment after declaration is working fine";
```

at first there is created the object `b` of the type `foo` using the implicitly defined by the compiler default constructor and then in the second statement there is used the assignment operator that is explicitly defined in the class. As it follows from the definition of the operator it assigns data member `str` with a temporary object of type `std::string` that is constructed from the used string literal. It is possible because the class `std::string` has a corresponding conversion constructor.